# IMAP Response not proper

Tags: c#, sockets, imap

I am working on C# MailClient and which is follow IMAP Protocol, but I am getting wrong response that means the response will give me some repetitive resul.
Like say first time I am sending command like this.

```
 byte[] commandBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(("$ UID FETCH " + index + " (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM DATE)])\r\n"));
```

and second time I am sending like this.

```
byte[] commandBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(("$ UID FETCH " + index + " (BODYSTRUCTURE)" + "\r\n"));
```

so I am getting again first command result in twice or more than 2 times;
and some times it's continue giving me first result.

my Response() method is like this.

```
 private string Response()
{
    string response = string.Empty;
    byte[] data = new byte[_imapClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
    int ret = _imapNs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data,0,ret);
    return response;
}
```

_imapClient is a object of an

```
private TcpClient _imapClient;
```

and I am taking value of _imapClient is like this.

```
    public string GetMessageBodyStructure(int index)
{
    byte[] commandBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(("$ UID FETCH " + index + " (BODYSTRUCTURE)" + "\r\n"));
    _imapNs.Write(commandBytes, 0, commandBytes.Length);
    _imapNs.Flush();
    return Response();
}
```

Where I am wrong correct me thanks..

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use char array:

   `byte[] commandBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("$ UID FETCH " + index + " (BODYSTRUCTURE)" + "\r\n");`
2. TCP is *stream* based and not *message* based.

This means that nothing guarantees that the entire message is received with the same `Read`. A `Read` may receive a half message, a complete message or two messages. You need to handle that accordingly.

3 Use `return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, ret);`

4 There are several open source IMAP libraries out there. Why not use one of those since you are new to socket programming?

Comment: I Remove the Char Array and also add the Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, ret);
but still same.

Comment: Good. Now you have only #2 left to fix. If you can't find out how (by googling), #4 is your only option.

Comment: 2.TCP is stream based and not message based.

what do you mean by this.

Comment: I described it under: Nothing says that your entire message will arrive when you use `_imapNs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);`.

Comment: Dear@jgauffin Thanks for suggetion, plz look at my modify code and correct me if I am wrong.